# importing new fonts @font-face font-family

Tags: css, fonts, sass, font-family

Hellow i have a problem with importing fonts from folder.

I`m using gulp and browsersync on index.php throught proxy to my VH.

When I want to set up a background I have to use this url

```
background-image:  url('http://ekozone.local/src/img/logo.png');
```

Now when I try to make new font family by doing

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "BarlowBlack"; 
    src: url('http://ekozone.local/src/Barlow-Black.ttf') format('ttf'),
  }
```

Nothing happens, I was trying many ways to get to my fonts

```
src: url('../../../src/Barlow-Black.ttf') format('ttf')
```

/\ this one was before i moved it to same level as index

```
src: url('Barlow-Black.ttf') format('ttf')
```

This is how my structure looks like
[STRUCTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgQBw.png)

If someone can help me it would be great... And I was reading questions about this but nothing works for me... probably im doing something wrong.
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have div or another HTML element with class `divClass`, in CSS you have to specify whichone font family you need to use:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "BarlowBlack"; 
    src: url('http://ekozone.local/src/Barlow-Black.ttf'),
}
.divClass {
    font-family: "BarlowBlack";
    background-image:  url('http://ekozone.local/src/img/logo.png');
}
```

This should work for you.

Or if you would like to use your font, use instead of http link:

```
src: url('../Barlow-Black.ttf');
```

Comment: I messed up my path so badly ;) but thanks for help and I did know that i have to specify where to use it , still thanks for help :)